# Counting effective line count in sources by PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I am writing a PHP program which reads file with `file_get_contents` then attempts to count effective lines in that source file. It must not count empty lines or lines containing comments only. Sample file:

```
<?php

/**
  * blah blah
  */
class Test {
     // testfunc
     function testfunc(){


         return;
     }
}
```

The number of lines in such a file should be 5. Here is what I've got so far:

```
    $f=file_get_contents($this->file);
    $f=preg_replace('|/\*.*?\*/|s','',$f);
    $f=preg_replace('/^\s*$/','',$f);  // <-- does not work
    $f=preg_replace("/\n\n*/s","\n",$f);
    $count=count(explode("\n",$f));
```

But for some reason it does not eliminate white-spaces. Is there a better way to get this done?

---

The following code does the job, since I don't care much about the spaces, but I still wonder, why my original line labeled "does not work" is not removing spaces from empty lines. Is there some extra character at the end? File format is unix.

```
    $f=preg_replace('/ */','',$f);   // removes all spaces properly.
```

Comment: Be careful with the pattern `/\*.*?\*/`: it will break on input like this: `$s = 'string /* literal';`

Comment: Do non PHP parts (e.g. HTML) count as lines as well, or won't they?

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc

Comment: And if you feel compelled to reinvent the wheel, please do it properly. Write a lexer for the PHP lexer. It's not that hard.

Comment: @deinan: He don't even needs to. He can just use `token_get_all()` ;)

Comment: @delnan: "Write a lexer for PHP. It's not that hard". Clearly you haven't tried to do this: interpolated string literals in several varieties, embedded HTML and/or comment text that might contain code-like structures, ... token_get_all uses the PHP lexer, which has a solution built in.

Comment: @IraBaxter: String interpolation shouldn't need to be adressed (one only needs to recognize string literals). HTML or whetever output is embedded can be skipped over, they're marked by php tags. Comments are recognized just fine by any lexer worth being called such. I see that a lexer isn't a project one does in an off hour, but it's manageable and . As for existing solutions: Yes, those are obviously better *except* if it's done for the sake of learning. And I assume that's the case here, as LOC counting is an old problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/^[\s\t]*$/` to be `/^\s*$/ms` and that should fix it.
The `\s` class includes tabs, so no need to add `\t`.  The `s` makes it match newline characters and the `m` option makes `^` and `$` work when data contains multiple lines (matches line breaks).

Also, it might be better to change `/\n\n/s` to be `/[\r\n]{2,}/`.

Comment: Awesome. This solved it for me, thanks. I'll re-format my question to reflect my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and then test each line.

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strlen(trim($line)) > 0) {
        $total++;
    }
}
```

Then, you're set up to test for other conditions as well, such as comment lines and what not.  I suspect that this will be faster than doing a find/replace on a potentially large document, but you should test it either way, and choose the fastest method.

Comment: @Pekka, comments are going to get tricky.  I just added a note explaining that he can use this pattern to step through the lines, and add other conditions later.